# Django order model by date and move models without date to the end

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model tickets, with a sum in it. I'm trying to make spending tickets by nearest expire date. But if I'm ordering by `date_expire`, it move `date_expire=None` models to the top. But `date_expire=None` means that ticket has no limit by time, and should be used after all tickets, that has time limit.

My code:

```py
ticket = Tickets.objects.filter(
                sum__gte=0,
                date_expire__gte=timezone.now(),
                user_id=user.id,
                burned=False
            ).order_by(
                'date_expire'
            ).first()
```

I can try to sort by sorted func with lambda key, but I think there's a better way to do this in orm

### **UPD**

I think i found a solution for myself.
Now my code looks like:

```py
ticket = Tickets.objects.filter(
                sum__gte=0,
                date_expire__gte=timezone.now(),
                user_id=user.id,
                burned=False
            ).annotate(
                has_date=Func(F('date_expire'), Value(None), function='IFNULL')
            ).order_by(
                '-has_date',
                'date_expire'
            ).first()
```

I used `annotate` function of `QuerySet` to make a new value `has_date` which is using an SQL func IFNULL, that returns `True` if field `date_expire` is `NULL`.

SQL field in query must be something like this:

```
IFNULL("tickets"."date_expire", NULL) AS "has_date"
```

And then i sort by `-has_date` first, to move all objects with `True` values under the `False` values.

Maybe there's a better way to do that, but that method works for my idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `F` expression with `nulls_first` or `nulls_last`. Check the [Using F() to sort null values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-to-sort-null-values) on the django documentation.

In your case:

```
from django.db.models import F

ticket = Tickets.objects.filter(
            sum__gte=0,
            date_expire__gte=timezone.now(),
            user_id=user.id,
            burned=False
        ).order_by(
            F('date_expire').desc(nulls_last=True)
        ).first()
```

Comment: Oh thanks! This is a better way than the way I found.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the official solution:

One method is to introduce a value that represents a ceiling value. So instead of using None for date_expire use a date 1000 years in the future like `12/31/3000`. That way this date is always later than your current dates.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i want to make something like "Expires: Never" in user's profile. I can also check a `year < 3000` when rendering values, but this is a horrible way i think.